# GridView imageviews are cropped

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, scaletype

I have a GridView in my android app and in each cell I have two imageviews. The problem is that I have to set one of the imageviews gravity to center, and when I do this the imageview gets cropped. I wanted to ask if there is a way to keep the aspect ratio of the image and prevent it from being cropped.
PS: if I don't use gravity center I can achieve this by using scaletype center , but in my app I need the image to be centered so I need to use gravity center.
Thanks very much 
Here's the layout code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bgcolor"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:paddingTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/shelf_center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />


    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`  with  `android:gravity="center"` it will do the trick.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" >
</ImageView>
```

Comment: Thanks , but didn't have any effect on the crop.

Comment: can you share screenshot of your grid